# I am not able to access the id inside both objects

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am new to angular, I am not able to post the values of the id inside Position and Department, for some reason, it is not accessing the id

addEmployee.model.ts

```
export class AddEmployee {

  Position: {
    id: string;
  };
  Department: {
    id: string;
  };
}
```

AddEmployeeService

```
DefineEmployee(addEmployee: AddEmployee) {
  const body: AddEmployee = {

    Position: {
      id: addEmployee.Position.id
    },

    Department: {
      id: addEmployee.Department.id
    }
  }
  return this.http.post('url', body);
}
```

AddEmployee.component.ts

```
onSubmit(form: NgForm) {

  return this.restService.DefineEmployee(form.value).subscribe((res: any) => {
    this.resetForm(form);
    console.log(res);
  }, error => {
    this.resetForm(form);
  })
}
```

addEmployee.component.html

```
<div class="form-group">

  //AddEmployee.Position.id comes up with undefined element 'id'

  <select [(ngModel)]="AddEmployee.Position.id" name="Position" Position="ngModel" class="form- 
             control customized-dropdown">
    <option [value]="item.id" *ngFor="let item of positions">{{item.name_FL}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: console log `addEmployee` in `DefineEmployee` to see where the values are and use them appropriately. Another suggestion would be to use reactive form rather than template driven form.

Comment: please add the contents of your `console.log(res)` to the question

Comment: @TheFabio when i console.log(res) it comes up with ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined in AddEmployeeService

Comment: I highly doubt this error to be generated by the `console.log` call... I will write an answer with my thoughts

Comment: @TheFabio yes you are write, I apologize, the error that comes up is saying: Position:
id: undefined, Department:
id: undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as the error is coming from the service `AddEmployeeService`, I believe the call to the service is not passing the parameters your function is expecting.

When you call `this.restService.DefineEmployee(form.value)`, I believe the `value` property does not have a `Position` or `Department` property.

you can test that by adding a debugger as indicated:

```
DefineEmployee(addEmployee: AddEmployee) {
  console.log(addEmployee);
  debugger;
  const body: AddEmployee = {

    Position: {
      id: addEmployee.Position.id
    },
    ...
```

that should help you fix the function

#### UPDATE

The Op posted the contents of the `addEmployee` varible as:

```
{
 "Position":"c8a06de6-58e1-439a6fc-08d7553139ac",
 "Department":"552ccb91-02f8-476b-adbc-08d7553136bf"
}
```

it seems the ids of Positions and Departments do not have an 'id' property in the "addEmployee" variable;

so to fix the issue, just remove the 'ids' form the `addEmployee` in the service

```
DefineEmployee(addEmployee: AddEmployee) {
  const body: AddEmployee = {

    Position: {
      id: addEmployee.Position // <<< here
    },

    Department: {
      id: addEmployee.Department  // <<< here
    }
  }
  return this.http.post('url', body);
}
```

Comment: I thought so as well, but please check out my question I posted the code in AddEmployeeService as I've added it in the body already with no results

Comment: if you add these debug lines i proposed, what does `console.log(addEmployee);` produce?

Comment: it shows that the value of the id has been passed to addEmployee.Position, so the value stayed at Position and id is coming up with undefined

Comment: can you please share the exact contents of what `console.log(addEmployee)` generates?

Comment: [object Object]

Comment: please replace `console.log(addEmployee)` with `console.log(JSON.stringify(addEmployee))` and post what you see

Comment: {"Position":"c8a06de6-58e1-439a-b6fc-08d7553139ac","Department":"552ccb91-02f8-476b-adbc-08d7553136bf"}